# При каком объеме данных необходимо делать масштабирование БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, масштабирование

Всем привет. Сейчас выпускаю в продакшн интернет-магазин + CRM-систему для него. Если с ИМ все понятно, товары и т.д. не будут превышать и 10000 строк, то вот с CRM совсем по-другому. Это логирование действий сотрудников, продажи и т.д., что за первые 2 года наберет под 1 млн записей в некоторых таблицах. В связи с этим заинтересовался масштабированием, много прочитал про шардинг, репликации и т.д., но нигде не написан объем данных, при которых производительность падает. БД mysql 5.6, innodb. При каких нагрузках нужно начинать заниматься масшабированием БД?

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от вашего приложения, используемого железа и степени прямоты рук разработчиков, администраторов и DBA

Где-то может быть плохо уже на базе в 1гб, где-то и полтора террабайта живут нормально.

Масштабированием базы занимаются когда объективно (это важно, именно объективно! Т.е. необходимы графики мониторинга производительности) дальнейший рост упирается в производительность базы.

Если упирается в чтение данных - то настраивается репликация и получается некоторое количество головной боли. Просто потому, что репликация в mysql сделана несколько больно. Например, есть [отдельный раздел](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features.html) особенностей поведения, которые надо учитывать в том числе в `SQL` запросах.

Если упираетесь в запись данных - то делается (на приложении) шардирование данных. И получается ещё сильно больше головной боли.